# Duvida usando Repository no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Fala pessoal!

Seguindo a ideia do boilerplate http://laravel-boilerplate.com tenho um repository assim:

```php
class EmpresaRepository extends BaseRepository 
{

    public function __construct(Empresa $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

e o ServiceProvider desta forma:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Empresa;
use App\Repositories\Backend\EmpresaRepository;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\Contracts\EmpresaRepositoryContract', function ($app) {
            return new EmpresaRepository(new Empresa());
        });
    }

}
```

Quero executar o seguinte teste:

```php
public function empresa_repository_pode_recuperar_empresas()
    {
        $repo = resolve('App\Repositories\Backend\EmpresaRepository');
        $empresas = factory(Empresa::class, 5)->create();
        $query_empresas = $repo->all();

        $this->assertEquals(count($empresas), count($query_empresas));
    }
```

O Problema que ocorre é: sempre que instancio um repository, ele cria uma nova instancia de Empresa, e o count($query_empresas) retorna sempre uma empresa a mais do que as já criadas com o factory.

Duvidas: 
Essa abordagem do repository sempre receber uma entidade está correta mesmo?

Como posso fazer esse teste passar?

Comment: Jovem, o seu serviceProvider foi registrado em config/app.php ?

Answer (score -3):

Olha até onde sei,

```php
  new Empresa()
```

não salva nada no banco, só instancia um objeto em memória.
Então o resultado do seu teste deveria estar correto.

Porém se esse teste é executado após algum outro que tenha inserido, pode ser que esteja pegando resíduo do teste anterior.

Talvez você não esteja usando o trait

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase
```

que reseta o banco a cada teste.

Espero ter ajudado alguém, qualquer coisa diz ae :)